# Error compiling bibliography

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I added this three new entries to my `.bib` file

```
@article{Koblitz,
  doi = {10.1090/s0025-5718-1987-0866109-5},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1090/s0025-5718-1987-0866109-5},
  year = {1987},
  month = jan,
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society ({AMS})},
  volume = {48},
  number = {177},
  pages = {203--203},
  author = {Neal Koblitz},
  title = {Elliptic curve cryptosystems},
  journal = {Mathematics of Computation}
}

@article{Miller,
  doi = {10.1007/3-540-39799-x_31},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39799-x_31},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  pages = {417--426},
  author = {Victor S. Miller},
  title = {Use of Elliptic Curves in Cryptography},
  booktitle = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  journal = {Springer},
  year = {1985}
}

@book{konheim,
  title={Computer security and Cryptography},
  author={Konheim, A.G.},
  isbn={9780470083970},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Wiley},
}
```

and then I get this error

```
./main.bbl:53: Use of \hyper@link@ doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
./main.bbl:53: Use of \BR@@lbibitem doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
./main.bbl:53: Argument of \BR@@bibitem has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
Runaway argument?
./main.bbl:53: Paragraph ended before \BR@@bibitem was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
./main.bbl:53: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...empa {\BR@@bibitem }\edef \Hy@tempb 
                                                  {\futurelet }\ifx \Hy@temp...
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
./main.bbl:53: Argument of \hyper@link has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
Runaway argument?
./main.bbl:53: Paragraph ended before \hyper@link was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.53 \bibitem
             [Kon07]{konheim}
)
./main.tex:302: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 53.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.302 \bibliography{main.bib}
                             
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 53.
<inserted text>
```

The bibliography was working correctly before adding this entries but now, if I try to remove them, it still fails. I've reviewed my .tex and there is nothing new so I'm not sure what it could be

Edit: Here is a minimal setup https://www.overleaf.com/read/qsdcjvrbsbnw but I see it to work fine. In my case it also works but If I try to recompile I get the mentioned error

As requested here is the main file

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Plantilla de la clase `scrbook` del paquete KOMA-script para la
% elaboración de un TFG siguiendo las directrices del la comisión del
% Grado en Matemáticas de la Universidad de Granada.

% Francisco Torralbo Torralbo
% miércoles, 29 de abril de 2020

\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{%
  fontsize=10pt,        % Tamaño de fuente
  paper=a4,             % Tamaño del papel
  headings=normal,      % Tamaño de letra para los títulos: small, normal, big
  % parskip=half,         % Espacio entre párrafos: full (una línea) o half (media línea)
  headsepline=false,    % Una linea separa la cabecera del texto
  cleardoublepage=empty,% No imprime cabecera ni pie en páginas en blanco 
  chapterprefix=false,  % No antepone el texto "capítulo" antes del número
  appendixprefix=false, % No antepone el texto "Apéndice" antes de la letra
  listof=totoc,             % Añade a la tabla de contenidos la lista de tablas y figuras
  index=totoc,              % Añade a la talba de contenidos una entrada para el índice
  bibliography=totoc,     % Añade a la tabla de contenidos una entrada para bibliografía
  BCOR=5mm,           % Reserva margen interior para la encuadernación. 
                        % El valor dependerá el tipo de encuadernado y del grosor del libro.
  DIV=10,             % Cálcula el diseño de página según ciertos 
                        % parámetros. Al aumentar el número aumentamos el ancho de texto y disminuimos el ancho del margen. Una opción de 14 producirá márgenes estrechos y texto ancho.
}

% INFORMACIÓN PARA LA VERSIÓN IMPRESA
% Si el documento ha de ser impreso en papel de tamaño a4 pero el tamaño del documento (elegido en \KOMAoptions con la ocpión paper) no es a4 descomentar la línea que carga el paquete `crop` más abajo. El paquete crop se encargará de centrar el documento en un a4 e imprimir unas guías de corte. El procedimiento completo para imprenta sería el siguiente:
% 0. Determinar, según el tipo de encuadernación del documento, el ancho reservado para el proceso de encuadernación (preguntar en la imprenta), es decir, la anchura del área del papel que se pierde durante el proceso de encuadernación. Fijar la varibale BCOR de \KOMAoptions a dicho valor.
% 1. Descomentar la siguiente línea e imprimir una única página con las guías de corte
% 2. Cambiar la opción `cross` por `cam` (o `off`) en el paquete crop y volver a compilar. Imprimir el documento (las guías de corte impresas no inferfieren con el texto).
% 3. Usar la página con las guías impresas en el punto 1 para cortar todas las páginas.

% \usepackage[a4, odd, center, pdflatex, cross]{crop} % Permite imprimir el documento en un a4 (si el tamaño es más pequeño) mostrando unas guías de corte. Útil para imprenta.

% VERSIÓN ELECTRÓNICA PARA TABLETA
% Las opciones siguientes seleccionan un tamaño de impresión similar a una tableta de 9 pulgadas con márgenes estrechos. Útil para producir una versión en pdf para ser leída en una tableta en lugar de impresa.
% Para que la portada quede centrada correctamente hay que editar el
% archivo `portada.tex` y eliminar el entorno `addmargin`

% \KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt, paper=19.7104cm:14.7828cm, twoside=false, BCOR=0cm, DIV=14}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAQUETES 
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{\textheight}% 
}{0.5ex}}%
\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Algoritmos 
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{parameter}

% CODIFICACIÓN E IDIOMA
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                % Codificación de caracteres

% Selección del idioma: cargamos por defecto inglés y español (aunque este último es el idioma por defecto para el documento). Cuando queramos cambiar de idioma escribiremos:
% \selectlanguage{english} o \selectlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage[english, spanish, es-nodecimaldot, es-noindentfirst, es-tabla]{babel}

% Opciones cargadas para el paquete babel:
  % es-nodecimaldot: No cambia el punto decimal por una coma en modo matemático.
  % es-noindentfirst: No sangra los párrafos tras los títulos.
  % es-tabla: cambia el título del entorno `table` de "Cuadro" a "Tabla"

% Otras opciones del paquete spanish-babel:
  \unaccentedoperators % Desactiva los acentos en los operadores matemáticso (p.e. \lim, \max, ...). Eliminar esta opción si queremos que vayan acentuados

% MATEMÁTICAS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % Paquetes matemáticas
% \usepackage{mathtools}                % Añade mejoras a amsmath
% \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}      % sólo se numeran las ecuaciones que se usan
% \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}                   % Proporciona el comando \mathscr para
                                      % fuentes de tipo manuscrito en modo matemático sin sobreescribir el comando \mathcal

% ====================

% TIPOGRAFÍA 
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% El paquete microtype mejora la tipografía del documento.
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

% Las tipografías elegidas para el documento, siguiendo la guía de estilo de la UGR,
% son las siguientes
% Normal font:          URW Palladio typeface. 
% Sans-serif font:  Gill Sans
% Monospace font:   Inconsolata
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc, osf]{mathpazo} \linespread{1.05}         
\usepackage[scaled=.95,type1]{cabin} % sans serif in style of Gill Sans
% Si el paquete cabin da error usar el siguiente comando en su lugar
% \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona} 
\usepackage{inconsolata}


% Selecciona el tipo de fuente para los títulos (capítulo, sección, subsección) del documento.
\setkomafont{disposition}{\sffamily\bfseries}

% Cambia el ancho de la cita. Al inicio de un capítulo podemos usar el comando \dictum[autor]{cita} para añadir una cita famosa de un autor.
\renewcommand{\dictumwidth}{0.45\textwidth} 

\recalctypearea % Necesario tras definir la tipografía a usar.

\usepackage{setspace}
% TABLAS, GRÁFICOS Y LISTADOS DE CÓDIGO
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Aumenta el espacio vertical entre las filas de un entorno tabular

\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
% Carpeta donde buscar los archivos de imagen por defecto
\graphicspath{{img/}}

% IMAGEN DE LA PORTADA
% Existen varias opciones para la imagen de fondo de la portada del TFG. Todas ellas tienen en logotipo de la universidad de Granada en la cabecera. Las opciones son las siguientes:
% 1. portada-ugr y portada-ugr-color: diseño con marca de agua basada en el logo de la UGR (en escala de grises y color).
% 2. portada-ugr-sencilla y portada-ugr-sencilla-color: portada únicamente con el logotipo de la UGR en la cabecera.
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
      % Indicar la imagen de fondo en el siguiente comando
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
            keepaspectratio]{portada-ugr-sencilla}%
            \vfill
}}}

% \usepackage{listings} % Para la inclusión de trozos de código

% CABECERAS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% Si queremos modificar las cabeceras del documento podemos usar el paquete
% `scrlayer-scrpage` de KOMA-Script. Consultar la documentación al respecto.
% \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% VARIOS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usepackage{showkeys}  % Muestra las etiquetas del documento. Útil para revisar las referencias cruzadas.

% ÍNDICE 
% Para generar el índice hay que compilar el documento con MakeIndex. Generalmente los editores se encargan de ello automáticamente.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% \index{} para añadir un elemento
% \index{main!sub} para añadir un elementos "sub" bajo la categoría "main".
% \index{termino|textbf} para dar formato al número de página (negrita).
% \index{termino|see{termino relacionado}} para crear una referencia cruzada

% Ejemplo: \index{espacio homogéneo}, \index{superficie!mínima}, \index{esfera|see{espacio homogéneo}}

% Activar los siguientes comandos para generar el índice terminológico. Ver también comandos al final de este documento para incluir dicho índice en el pdf final.
% \usepackage{makeidx}
% \makeindex

% Para revisar las entradas al índice conforme las incluimos en el documento es útil el siguiente paquete. Conviene observar que mientras esté cargado no se generará el índice.
%\usepackage{showidx} % Muestra en el margen del documento las entradas añadidas al índice. Útil para revisar el documento. Si está activo el índice no se genera

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% COMANDOS Y ENTORNOS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% Cargamos un archivo externo donde hemos incluido todos los comandos
% propios que vamos a usar en el documento.
\input{paquetes/comandos-entornos.tex}

\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\lceil #1 \rceil}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% INFORMACIÓN DEL TFG Y EL AUTOR
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xspace} % Para problemas de espaciado al definir comandos

\newcommand{\miTitulo}{Criptografía con curvas elípticas\xspace}
\newcommand{\miNombre}{Yábir García Benchakhtir\xspace}
\newcommand{\miGrado}{Doble Grado en Ingeniería Informática y Matemáticas}
\newcommand{\miFacultad}{Escuela Técnica Superior de Ingeniería Informática y Telecomunicaciones - Facultad de Ciencias}
\newcommand{\miUniversidad}{Universidad de Granada}
% Añadir tantos tutores como sea necesario separando cada uno de ellos
% mediante el comando `\medskip` y una línea en blanco
\newcommand{\miTutor}{
  Redacted \\ \emph{Álgebra} 
  % Añadir tantos tutores como sea necesario. 
}
\newcommand{\miCurso}{2020-2021\xspace}

% HYPERREFERENCES
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  % hidelinks,            % Enlaces sin color ni borde. El borde no se imprime
  linkbordercolor=0.8 0 0,
  citebordercolor=0 0.8 0,
  citebordercolor=0 0.8 0,
  colorlinks = true,            % Color en texto de los enlaces. Comentar esta línea o cambiar `true` por `false` para imprimir el documento.
  linkcolor = [rgb]{0.5, 0, 0}, % Color de los enlaces internos
  urlcolor = [rgb]{0, 0, 0.5},  % Color de los hipervínculos
  citecolor = [rgb]{0, 0.5, 0}, % Color de las referencias bibliográficas
    pdftitle={\miTitulo},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \miNombre, \miFacultad, \miUniversidad},%
  pdfsubject={Trabajo de fin de Grado},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
}

% Redefinición del estilo para mostrar las referencias cruzadas en la bibliografía.
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{{\footnotesize [%
    \ifcase #1 No citado%
    \or Citado en pág.~#2%
    \else Citado en págs. #2%
    \fi%
]}}

% Etiquetas en español para el comando \autoref
\def\chapterautorefname{Capítulo}
\def\appendixautorefname{Apéndice}
\def\sectionautorefname{Sección}
\def\subsectionautorefname{Subsección}
\def\figureautorefname{Fig.}
\def\tableautorefname{Tabla}

\def\teoremaautorefname{Teorema}
\def\proposicionautorefname{Proposición}
\def\lemaautorefname{Lema}
\def\corolarioautorefname{Corolario}
\def\definicionautorefname{Def.}
\def\observacionautorefname{Observación}
\def\ejemploautorefname{E.j.}

% Pone automáticamente un parántesis para las ecuaciones
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Ec.~(#1)\null}


% DIBUJOS

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.25cm}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}


% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% FRONTMATTER
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
\frontmatter % Desactiva la numeración de capítulos y usa numeración romana para las páginas

% \pagestyle{plain} % No imprime cabeceras

%\input{preliminares/portada}                    
%\input{preliminares/titulo}                     
%\input{preliminares/declaracion-originalidad}   
%\input{preliminares/dedicatoria}                % Opcional
%\input{preliminares/tablacontenidos}            
%\input{preliminares/agradecimientos}            % Opcional

% \pagestyle{scrheadings} % A partir de ahora sí imprime cabeceras

%\input{preliminares/resumen.tex}
%\input{preliminares/summary}                    
%\input{preliminares/introduccion}               

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% MAINMATTER
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter % activa la numeración de capítulos, resetea la numeración de las páginas y usa números arábigos

%\input{capitulos/introducion.tex}
\part*{Matemáticas}
%\input{capitulos/old_curvas.tex}
%\input{capitulos/curvas.tex}
%\input{capitulos/basic.tex}
%\input{capitulos/frobenius.tex}
%\input{capitulos/isogenias.tex}
\part*{Informática}
%\input{capitulos/logaritmo.tex}
%\input{capitulos/criterios.tex}
%\input{capitulos/estandares.tex}
%\input{capitulos/algoritmos_curvas.tex}
%\input{capitulos/libreria.tex}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% APPENDIX: Opcional
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%\appendix % Reinicia la numeración de los capítulos y usa letras para numerarlos
%\pdfbookmark[-1]{Apéndices}{appendix} % Alternativamente podemos agrupar los apéndices con un nuevo \part{Apéndices}

%\input{apendices/apendice01}
% Añadir tantos apéndices como sea necesario 

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% GLOSARIO: Opcional
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%\input{glosario} 

% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% BACKMATTER
% -------------------------------------------------------------------

\backmatter % Desactiva la numeración de los capítulos
\pdfbookmark[-1]{Referencias e Índices}{BM-Referencias}

% BIBLIOGRAFÍA
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbibpreamble{Las referencias se listan por orden alfabético. Aquellas referencias con más de un autor están ordenadas de acuerdo con el primer autor.\par\bigskip}
\bibliographystyle{alpha} 
\nocite{*}
\begin{small} % Normalmente la bibliografía se imprime en un tamaño de letra más pequeño.
\bibliography{main.bib}
\end{small}


% ÍNDICE TERMINOLÓGICO  (Opcional) 
%------------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Para incluir el índice terminológico es necesario descomentar los siguientes comandos. Incluir un índice terminológico es opcional

% \cleardoublepage 
% \begin{footnotesize} % Normalmente el índice se imprime en un tamaño de letra más pequeño.
% \printindex 
% \end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

and the bib file

```
@book{silverman,
      author        = "Joseph H Silverman",
      title         = "{The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves}",
      publisher     = "Springer",
      address       = "Dordrecht",
      series        = "Graduate Texts in Mathematics",
      year          = "2009",
      url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/1338326",
      doi           = "10.1007/978-0-387-09494-6",
}

@book{silverman2015rational,
  title={Rational Points on Elliptic Curves},
  author={Silverman, J.H. and Tate, J.T.},
  isbn={9783319185880},
  series={Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.es/books?id=2\_PLCQAAQBAJ},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer International Publishing}
}

@book{Washington,
      author        = "Lawrence C. Washington",
      title         = "{Elliptic curves: number theory and cryptography}",
      publisher     = "Chapman and Hall/CRC",
      series        = "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications",
      year          = "2008",
      ISBN          = "978-1-4200-7146-7",
}

@book{hartshorne,
  author        = "Robin Hartshorne",
  title         = "{Algebraic Geometry}",
  publisher     = "Springer",
  series        = "Graduate texts in mathematics",
  year          = "1977",
  ISBN          = "978-1-4419-2807-8",
}

@book{husemoller,
  author        = "Dale Husemoller",
  title         = "{Elliptic Curves}",
  publisher     = "Springer-Verlag New York",
  series        = "Graduate Texts in Mathematics",
  year          = "2004",
  ISBN          = "978-0-387-95490-5",
}


@book{galbraith2012mathematics,
  title={Mathematics of Public Key Cryptography},
  author={Galbraith, S.D.},
  isbn={9781107013926},
  lccn={2011042606},
  url={https://books.google.es/books?id=owd76BElvosC},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}


@misc{proyectivo,
  author = {Francisco Javier Gallego Rodrigo},
  title = {{Geometría priyectiva}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.cartagena99.com/recursos/alumnos/temarios/GP\%20primera\%20parte.pdf}",
  note = "[Online]"
}

@misc{isogenias,
  author = {Kristen Hendricks},
  title = {{On the proof of hasse theorem}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://share.cocalc.com/share/5d54f9d642cd3ef1affd88397ab0db616c17e5e0/www/edu/2004/24g/projects/kristen.pdf}",
  note = "[Online]"
}

@misc{asociativa,
    author = {Adam Block},
    title = {{Introduction to Elliptic Curves}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/UMS\%20Talk\%203.pdf}",
    note = "[Online]"
}

@misc{interseccion,
    author = {Hulst},
    title = {{A proof of Bezout's theorem using the Euclidean algorithm}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/HulstBach.pdf}",
    note = "[Online]"
}

@misc{ecuacion_weiss,
    author = {Dino Festi},
    title = {{Notes on Elliptic Curves}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/dfesti/EllipticCurvesNotes.pdf}",
    note = "[Online]"
}

@book{menezes,
    author        = "Darrel Hankerso - Alfred Menezes - Scott Vanstone",
    title         = "{Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography}",
    publisher     = "Springer-Verlag New York",
    series        = "Springer Professional Computing",
    year          = "2003",
    ISBN          = "0-387-95273-X",
}

@misc{tangente,
    author = {Andrew V. Sutherlan},
    title = {{Introduction to Arithmetic Geometry}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-782-introduction-to-arithmetic-geometry-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_782F13_lec17.pdf}",
    note = "[Online]"
}

@misc{ejemplo:orden,
    author = {Alvaro Lozano Robledo},
    title = {{Ejemplo del ordeen de un punto}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://math.stackexchange.com/a/512825}",
    note = "[Online]"
}

@article{diffie1976new,
  title={New directions in cryptography},
  author={Diffie, Whitfield and Hellman, Martin},
  journal={IEEE transactions on Information Theory},
  volume={22},
  number={6},
  pages={644--654},
  year={1976},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@misc{sec2,
    author = {Certicom Research},
    title = {{Standards for Efficient Cryptography SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters}},
    howpublished = "\url{http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf}",
    note = "[Online]",
    year={2010}
}

@article{Koblitz,
  doi = {10.1090/s0025-5718-1987-0866109-5},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1090/s0025-5718-1987-0866109-5},
  year = {1987},
  month = jan,
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society ({AMS})},
  volume = {48},
  number = {177},
  pages = {203--203},
  author = {Neal Koblitz},
  title = {Elliptic curve cryptosystems},
  journal = {Mathematics of Computation}
}

@article{Miller,
  doi = {10.1007/3-540-39799-x_31},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39799-x\_31},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  pages = {417--426},
  author = {Victor S. Miller},
  title = {Use of Elliptic Curves in Cryptography},
  booktitle = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  journal = {Springer},
  year = {1985}
}

@book{konheim,
  title={Computer security and Cryptography},
  author={Konheim, A.G.},
  isbn={9780470083970},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Wiley},
}
```

Edit: After trying to minimize the example to post it here I've found that my error appeared after trying to do

```
\footnote{Capítulo 1 de \cite{Washington}}
```

in one of the chapters

Comment: Please also provide a full but minimal example that uses the bibtex data you provided. Otherwise we have no idea what you are doing

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The fact that the error still occurs may well be due to the fact that its still listed in the aux-files. Just delete all the aux-files LaTeX creates (for "Document.tex" this is everything named "Document.***", except the .tex and .bib-file) and compile again. This should delete what causes the hickup. For the error, it may be the underscore in the Miller-item. Try to write it as `https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39799-x\_31` instead (escape the `_` by `\\`). If it's not that, listen to daleif and post an MWE.

Comment: @daleif Sorry. I'm not familiar by the rules of this forum and in others sometimes I get warnings if I try to add much code. I've added a link to overleaf at the end.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Thank you for your suggestion. In my case I still get the error mentioned

Comment: Sadly links tend to rot over time, please copy the example here. Then others will also have benefit from your question in the future.

Comment: Unrelated: If you are a beginner: never use the `\def` command. If overwrites without warning and thus you can make a lot of damage with it.

Comment: The only problem I get with this data and the overleaf MWE is `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor` using undefined stuff and the `_` in the `\title`. Everything else compiles just fine.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for the help and the suggestion for the command. I've added the complete principal .tex file with the .bib file here. Sorry for the spanish comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127022/discussion-between-yabir-garcia-and-daleif).

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am unable to reproduce the issues you say you are getting. Sometimes, when BibTeX and/or LaTeX get confused, it's best to delete all auxiliary files and to start over with a full recompilation cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Whatever else you do, please be sure to correct a number of *bibliographic* errors in the `Miller` entry. To begin with, it wasn't published as a journal article but in a conference proceedings volume. Hence, do please the entry type from `@article` to `@inproceedings`. You should also correct the `booktitle` field and back-fill information about the volume's `editor`.

[image]

Observe that because you're using the ancient `alpha` bib style, fields such as `url`, `doi`, and `isbn` are simply ignored.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{Koblitz,
  doi =     {10.1090/s0025-5718-1987-0866109-5},
  url =     {https://doi.org/10.1090/s0025-5718-1987-0866109-5},
  year =    {1987},
  month =   jan,
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society ({AMS})},
  volume =  {48},
  number =  {177},
  pages =   {203--203},
  author =  {Neal Koblitz},
  title =   {Elliptic curve cryptosystems},
  journal = {Mathematics of Computation}
}
@incollection{Miller,
  doi =       {10.1007/3-540-39799-x_31},
  url =       {https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39799-x_31},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address =   {Berlin and Heidelberg},
  pages =     {417--426},
  author =    {Victor S. Miller},
  title =     {Use of Elliptic Curves in Cryptography},
  editor =    {Hugh C. Williams},
  booktitle = {Advances in Cryptology---CRYPTO '85 Proceedings},
  series =    {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  volume =    {218},
  xxjournal = {Springer},
  year =      {1985}
}
@book{konheim,
  title =     {Computer Security and Cryptography},
  author =    {Konheim, Alan G.},
  isbn =      {978-0471947837},
  year =      {2007},
  publisher = {Wiley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{alpha} % or: \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```